# How to find reference file used?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I know how to reference an external library. However now i am trying to work on a code example, and want to know this in reverse. So some libraries are used, and I dont know which dll's are used. Thus which dll's should I reference to use them in my code ?

Like this;

```
// main program
using myhidden.api.net
```

How to detect which dll file was called here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see on `Object Browser`;

- Add a reference to the DLL file.
- Right click it in the list.
- Click `View` in `Object Browser`.

[image]

Comment: thanks
for those with the same problem, under menu view >other windows > object browser, click the refrence and right corner below displays path and file.

Comment: There is no Object Browser in Other Windows. It is in View->Object Browser. Can you send me a screenshot or something?

Answer (score 0):

What can do depends on what your situation is.

If you have just a code file and no information about the other DLLs used AT ALL, your options are very limited.  About all you can do is search Google for the strings in the namespace and poke around at whatever site you found the code to see if there's any information about what DLLs are used.

If you know that the namespace comes from one of several DLLs and you have the DLLs, do as Mr. Gonul suggests in his answer.

Comment: @SonerGönül I can change it to Mr. Gönül if you'd prefer.  :)  Or would Mr. Soner have been more nearly correct?

Comment: Say whatever you want. But I guess Mr [Surname] is the right assumption. Right :) ?

Comment: LOL Mr., Mrs, Miss, Mz, Senior, Hey Dude, or maybe they all are incorect and it is Your Majesty :)